# using sqoop to update hive table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop data out of a MySQL database where I have a table with both a primary key and a last_updated field.  I am trying to essentially get all records that were recently updated and overwrite the current records in the hive warehouse

I have tried the following command

```
sqoop job --create trainingDataUpdate -- import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/analytics \
--username user \
--password-file /sqooproot.pwd \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column last_updated \
--last-value '2015-02-13 11:08:18' \
--table trainingDataFinal \
--merge-key id \
--direct --hive-import \
--hive-table analytics.trainingDataFinal \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--map-column-hive last_updated=TIMESTAMP
```

and I get the following error

```
15/02/13 14:07:41 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: SemanticException Line 2:17 Invalid path ''hdfs://dev.cluster.com:8020/user/hdfs/_sqoop/13140640000000520_32226_hwhjobdev_cluster.com_trainingDataFinal'': No files matching path hdfs://dev.cluster.com:8020/user/hdfs/_sqoop/13140640000000520_32226_dev.cluster.com_trainingDataFinal
15/02/13 14:07:42 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 64
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:385)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:335)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:239)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

I thought by including the `--merge-key` it would be able to overwrite the old records with new records.  Does anyone know if this is possible in sqoop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sqoop can do it.
--merge-key is only used by sqoop-merge not import

also see http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764421